# RollingAppander always null instead of return values

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, log4net

My Web Config in Web APi as below

```
 <appender name="MyLogger" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="RenameFileInCode.txt" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="5" />
  <!-- rollingStyle value="Size" /-->
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <threshold value="DEBUG" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger %newline%message%newline%exception%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
    <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
    <levelMax value="ERROR" />
  </filter>
</appender>
```

and My Method For Handling Ex. is like below

```
  public static void MaintainLog(string objname, Exception e)
    {
        //string LogName = objname + ".txt";
        string LogName = "SCRMpro_Log.txt";
        var user = UserManager.GetUserById(WebUtility.GetCurrentUserId());
        string filePath = GetClientWiseFilePath(user, "LOG"); //"//ErrorLogFile//";
        filePath = filePath + LogName;
        // Bind to the root hierarchy of log4net
        log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy root =
          log4net.LogManager.GetRepository()
            as log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy;

        if (root != null)
        {
            // Bind to the RollingFileAppender
            log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender rfa =
              (log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)root.Root.GetAppender("RollingLogFileAppender");

            if (rfa != null)
            {
                // Assign the value to the appender
                rfa.File = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filePath);

                // Apply changes to the appender
                rfa.ActivateOptions();
            }
        }
```

and in this method i'm not able to get RollingFileAppander Value its always null

```
log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender rfa =
          (log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)root.Root.GetAppender("RollingLogFileAppender");
```

can anyone had this solution much appreciated.

Comment: The most likely cause is that you haven't loaded the log4net configuration. If you have though, you will need to debug it: set a breakpoint on the `root.Root.GetAppender("MyLogger")` call, look at the logger, and see if it a) has the appender loaded and b) it has the name you expect. Oh, and the usual way to do this is something like `LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders().OfType<RollingFileAppender>().FirstOrDefault()`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to give the logger name:

```
     (log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender)root.Root.GetAppender("MyLogger");
```